# Is it possible to limit a StreamField to accept exactly two blocks?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

The title says it all, I haven't been able to find any other information online. I'm wondering if it is possible for me to get

```
secondary_links = StreamField([
    ('Page', SerialisedPageChooserBlock())])
```

to accept exactly two blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible as of Wagtail 1.12, with the [`min_num` and `max_num` properties on StreamBlock](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#streamblock):

```
secondary_links = StreamField(
    StreamBlock([
        ('Page', SerialisedPageChooserBlock())
    ], min_num=2, max_num=2)
)
```